# Does not having relations in a database has any disadvantages except data consistency?

Tags: php, mysql

For a small application, (For which I validate data at client side and server side as well), If I choose a database model which does not define any FOREIGN KEYS,  how is it going to adversely affect my application in the future? Are those pitfalls manageable?

**To simplify the question with an example:**
I have a task management application which contains two tables: Tasks, and Milestones. Every task has some milestones.
Columns of Tasks table are :

task_id, task_title .

Columns of Milestone table are:

parent_task_id, milestone_title

Now the column parent_task_id should be one of the task_id in the Tasks table.

**Now question is**
What if I opt to validate the parent_task_id in php and don't create a foreign key to task_id column of tasks table?

**Example Pseudocode:**

```
$array = store_query_results_in_array('select task_id from tasks where 1', $con);

If (!is_in($task, $array)) {
    throw $error;
}
```

Comment: So lots of db administrator/developers works hard to find the best way to work with dbs and you want go on the other direction because you know better than everyone else?

Comment: That's why I asked, before actually going to the other direction :). Just to learn the why, atleast the basic 'why's' if not  all of the 'reasons' which are probably beyond my understandig level.

Comment: But 100 likes to your How to eat an elephant... =D

Comment: The basic why is because with the restriction you guarantee data consistency so every programmer doesnt have to. You concentrate that task in a single place instead of every application. Making mantainance more easy.

Comment: for searching not so much.  but when inserting, updating and deleting constraints are really useful.  if you have milestones with task ids, and there are no tasks with that id in the tasks table, you are in trouble.  data is the most important thing, not code.  if you lose data, it does not matter how sexy your code is and what unit tests you wrote.  so if working with relational databases, you should make full use of constraints.